# Periodically, partially update aspx page using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to use only jquery to update a method which is reading account information periodically from database every 60 minutes.  I do not want to refresh or load the whole aspx page while I’m refreshing only that portion of the page. Is there any way for accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers extensive [Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) support.

If you want to make a GET request, you can use the $.get method. If you want to update a DOM element, you can use the $.load method. The general $.ajax method offers greater flexibility.

Comment: Then it would be still jquery? Sorry I'm new in this subject
For:
 <div class=example> function which reads from SQL </div>
How can I approach will appreciate any example?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

use a javascript timer and jquery's ajax functions to query your .aspx page or script file, periodically at a certain interval.

Comment: I am new in that subject,
could you please give me example?
if i have:
<div class=example>
  function which reads from SQL
</div>

how can I write javascript timer and then  use jquery's ajax funtion?
Thank you in advance